# Kio kaj kie estas la dana urbo Arĥangelsk?

Tags: books

Mi estas leganta "Paŝoj al plena posedo" de William Auld. En la unua legaĵo troviĝas tiu frazo:

> Mia amiko, Ripsrops, veturis antaŭ nelonge per sia beleta ĉaro, vi scias, tiu „Mercedes“, inter **Arĥangelsk** kaj Kopenhago sur la ŝoseo.

Kio kaj kie estas Arĥangelsk? Mi guglis kaj nur trovis [Arĥangelsko](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar%C4%A5angelsko), sed estas en Rusujo, 2 000 kilometroj for de Kopenhago. Verŝajne ne estas tiu urbo. Sed kiu? Ĉu ekzistas?

---

**Redakto:** Kial mi pensas ke ne estas tiu urbo?

Ŝajnas al mi ke oni ne kutime aŭtas inter du urboj separataj por 3 000 kilometroj kaj unu maro (la Balta Maro). Kaj kiam oni tion faras, oni ne prezentas la afero kiel tute normala kaj komprenebla. <s>Plie, mi ne certas ĉu ekzistas "ŝoseo" inter la du urboj: Google Maps nur trovas vojojn kun pramŝipo.</s> Mi eraris, mi serĉis la vojon *piede* anstataŭ *aŭte*: ŝajnas ke oni [bone](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Arkhangelsk,+Arkhangelsk+Oblast,+Russia/Copenhagen,+Denmark/@58.6257076,25.7772601,4.75z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x441833f755c232e1:0x403eec437ac89a31!2m2!1d40.5505769!2d64.5458549!1m5!1m1!1s0x4652533c5c803d23:0x4dd7edde69467b8!2m2!1d12.5683372!2d55.6760968!3e0) povas aŭti inter la du urboj. Sed 3 200 kilometroj! Ĉu estas normala vojaĝo en nordaj landoj???

Comment: Kial vi pensas ke ne estas tiu urbo?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani: Mi redaktis mian demandon por respondi tion.

Comment: Laŭ mi, l'aŭtoro simple uzis la vorton «ĉaro» anstataŭ «aŭto» tie.  En la sama alineo li parolas pri «benzinputo».

Comment: @Ainar-G : dankon, mi scias kio estas "Mercedes" ;)

Comment: Nu, 3.200 km estas tutnormala distanco por veturi, ne nur en nordaj landoj.